# Fastapi Redirect to endpoint not result

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I am using the last version of Fastapi on Ubuntu. I struggle on an endpoint, the code is below.

The  endpoint "`/redirect`" should redirects to "`/redirected`".
It works when I try it with the   "openai /docs  testing tool" from Fastapi but not when I try with Postman or Curl. I get no output and

the server logs is  : `" INFO:     127.0.0.1:49646 - "GET /redirect HTTP/1.1" 307 Temporary Redirect"`

the code:

```
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
from fastapi import Depends
...
...
...
@app.get("/redirect")
async def redirect( ):
    response = RedirectResponse(url='/redirected')
    return response

@app.get("/redirected")
    async def redirected():
    return {"message": "you've been redirected"}
```

Expected behaviour from the get request on "/redirect" is :

```
{"message": "you've been redirected"}
```

DO you know why it is not working with Curl or Postman.

Thank you in advance

Comment: That's the expected behavior. When you use a tool like Postman, it doesn't follow redirect responses (at least by default). When you access it in the browser, it receives the 307 response and then follows the redirect URL in it.

Comment: Thank you , it was exactly the missing information. I found the option in postman  :)